# Linux command line / shell terminology

Tags: linux, shell, command, terminology

I'm a little confused about the terminology I should use when referring to Linux command line programs and commands.

If I were to execute a command such as:

```
mkdir testing_dir
```

Would "testing_dir" be called an 'operand' to the program mkdir, or an 'argument' or a 'parameter'?

Another question I have is, what terminology would you use to describe the following process?

```
find *.txt | grep a | grep b
```

Could I say; the output of the "find" program is piped (redirected) to the input of the grep program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question, it is an "argument". That is why in C programs, the main prototype is `int main(int argc, char** argv)`. `argc` means argument count, and `argv` means argument vector.

For the second, it is "piped". (Because it is done with the pipe `|` charactor, and/or the data is passed from one program, like it is going through a pipe.) Generally, `stdout` is only called "redirected" when it is sent to a file with the `>` operator.

Answer (score 2):

1. Most people would call it the argument.
2. Yes, it's piped.

Answer (score 1):

- Argument or parameter rather than operand , while mkdir is a command , not a operater
- Yes, the output is piped to the input parameter of the next command.

Comment: Strictly speaking, an argument is the value assigned to a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There are no operands to commands, operators are having operands. For commands, they are arguments. Since the mkdir is a command,surely the name is an argument.

And about the second one..  The first output is given into the second command as input. Redirects are usually used with the operators > , >> and 2> 2>>